# Error: No results matching query were found for luarocks in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, luarocks

I just installed and built `torch` following the instructions on the official website [here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_), on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite. However I found `luarocks` cannot install any package with the command

```
luarocks install <package_name>
```

The error message is always

> Error: No results matching query were found

here I tried `<package_name>` being `csvigo`, `image`, `cv`, which were all successful in Ubuntu.

So, any ideas about it?

Answer (score -2):

lua + luarocks is a mess, stay away from it.

you can add the parameter `--from=http://rocks.moonscript.org/dev`

you can use `torch/bin/luarocks` or one of the other custom builds.

in the long term it won't help you:

lua + luarocks is a mess, stay away from it.